# Efecto de escritura - Typing effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

El efecto funciona bien pero al seguir bajando o subiendo con el scroll la velocidad aumenta demasiado si se a que se debe pero no se como arreglarlo, alguna solución?

```js
var i = 0;
var texto = 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat';
var velocidad = 500;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < texto.length) {
    document.getElementById("escribir").innerHTML += texto.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, velocidad);
  }
}

function Scroll() {
  let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scrollTop > 264) {
    typeWriter()
  }
  
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",Scroll)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <p id="escribir"></p>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo dos métodos para solucionar tu fallo:

- El primero seria borrar el `eventListener` si ya no es necesario
- El segundo tener una variable que te indique que ya esta escribiendo y saltarte la ejecución de nuevo en caso de ser true

```js
var i = 0;
var texto = 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, placeat';
var velocidad = 500;

let escribiendo = false

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < texto.length) {
    document.getElementById("escribir").innerHTML += texto.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, velocidad);
  }
}

function Scroll2() {

  if (escribiendo) return

  let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scrollTop > 264) {
    escribiendo = true
    typeWriter()
  }
  
}

function Scroll1() {

  let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scrollTop > 264) {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", Scroll1)
    typeWriter()
  }
  
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",Scroll1)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="escribir" style="padding: 1000px 0;"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, tienes idea de como se llama o como agregarle la barra | que parpadea cuando dejamos de escribir?

Comment: Prueba buscando "blinking cursor html"